# How to assign application to all desktops (spaces) of Mac OS X Lion using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to create an Application on Mac OS X Lion which requires application to be assigned to All Desktops (Spaces). This can be manually done by Right clicking on application's dock icon and Selecting **Options > Assign To > All Desktops**. But, I need to find a way to do this via Objective C. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use method [`setCollectionBehavior:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setCollectionBehavior:) of `NSWindow` with the [`NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setCollectionBehavior:) bitwise flag.

It will make the window visible on all spaces.

```
NSUInteger collectionBehavior;

// Gets the current collection behavior of the window
collectionBehavior = [ myWindow collectionBehavior ];

// Adds the option to make the window visible on all spaces
collectionBehavior |= NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces;

// Sets the new collection behaviour
[ myWindow setCollectionBehavior: collectionBehavior ];
```

**Note**

This method was introduced in Mac OS X 10.6.

On Mac OS X 10.5, you'll need to use the [`canBeVisibleOnAllSpaces:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004151-AppendixA) method of `NSWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just tried this solution and it works like a charm for Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Works with Mavericks' desktops, too, it seems.